# Running valgrind on mac os 10.11 produces error

Tags: c, macos, valgrind

When I try running valgrind on a very simple hello_world.c program, I got a lot of errors (most are repetition of the same functions). I asked my professor who pointed out that these functions belong to C++. Is this a problem with valgrind not fully supporting mac os? If yes, can anyone suggest an alternative to valgrind on mac os?

```
==3766==    by 0x7FFF5FC0853B: dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*,
dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*,
std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)

==3766==    by 0x7FFF5FC0853B: dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, 
dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, 
std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)


==3766== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3766==     in use at exit: 706,517 bytes in 906 blocks
==3766==   total heap usage: 1,541 allocs, 635 frees, 1,282,197 bytes     
allocated
==3766== 
==3766== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3766==    definitely lost: 5,713 bytes in 29 blocks
==3766==    indirectly lost: 5,512 bytes in 24 blocks
==3766==      possibly lost: 5,848 bytes in 127 blocks
==3766==    still reachable: 43,570 bytes in 363 blocks
==3766==         suppressed: 645,874 bytes in 363 blocks
==3766== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's *impossible* to say anything for certain. All we can do is guess, and guess badly.

Comment: Also "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow...". From ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

@trojanfoe has has already pointed out that Instruments is the way to do it on the MAC. Personally though I've had success using both. You can use a suppressions file to hide the `noise` just be careful what you hide.

Add this to your valgrind command to generate them as it runs.

```
--gen-suppressions=all
```

You then add these to a fill and use it as follows...

```
--suppressions=./mysuppressions.supp
```

You can find out more here.

https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto

Don't stop using valgrind because it has some warts on the mac. It's a great tool.

Answer (score -1):

[Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/) is the profiler to use under OSX and is included with Xcode.

Comment: Instruments does not implement the same features as valgrind, which has many other uses besides "profiling." This is a one liner answer which does not help explain the situation with valgrind on OSX.